# XDK app emulator and app not connecting to external web service/website

Tags: android, html, connection

I have a HTML5 app on Intel's XDK emulator which is trying to get some json data from an external site. The app on emulator is able to connect to localhost or ip address on internal network, but not to externally hosted sites. Can any one please help with any particular declaration/setting we need to look at? I am new on XDK.

Comment: can you show us the ip address you are using or try to run 10.0.2.2:(port) instead of 127.0.1.1:(port)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to connect to an external website by its host name. Trouble is it is not connecting to an external site. Setup is XDK on my laptop is accessing http://localhost/getjson.php and is working fine. But same is not working with http://www.example.com/getjson.php

Comment: I am able to connect using localhost/internal ip address inside the network

Comment: oh ok, umm you can add this code after know the response: `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and compare the [result](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) and tell us what is the error. I cant think of something else

Comment: code is some thing like - $.get('http://www.example.com/getjson.php', function() {
    alert("success");
})
.error(function() {
    alert("error");
})

Comment: after debugging, the json output is coming out, but JSON.parse() function is what is not returning any thing/stuck. Localhost php 5.4 json_encode and host server side php 5.2 json_encode function might be the problem.

Comment: can you provide part of the code?